# Is it a good idea to put all assembly: WebResource in the same cs file?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, resources

I have a .NET library, with some WebControls.

These webControls have Embed Resources.
And we declare them like it, in all webcontrols for each cs file:

Something like this:

```
 [assembly: WebResource("IO.Css.MyCSS.css", "text/css")]
    namespace MyNamespace.MyClass
    {
         [ParseChildren(true)]
         [PersistChildren(false)]
         [Designer(typeof(MyNamespace.MyClassDesigner))]
         public class QuickTip : Control, INamingContainer
         {
        //My code...
          }
    }
```

Would it be a good idea to create a cs file and include all WebResource declarations there?

Example a cs file with just:

```
     [assembly: WebResource("IO.Css.MyCSS.css", "text/css")]
     [assembly: WebResource("IO.Image.MyImage.png", "image/png")]
//And many other WebResources of all WebControls of the Assembly
```

Comment: did you consider asking at Code Review.SE?

Comment: @gnat I don't think this is regarding code style but rather architectural decisions.

Comment: This is an architectural question, and as such is off topic on Code Review.

Comment: @MichaelK, how to move this question do Code Review site?

Comment: GuilhermeJSantos We won't be migrating it to Code Review, as @MichaelK already mentioned it's **off topic** for them.

Comment: @YannisRizos, sorry I misunderstood what MichaelK mentioned. Thanks to emphasize the **off topic**.

Comment: No worries, your question is perfectly on topic for Programmers (Also MichaelK is a Code Review moderator)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, this is not a good practice.  You want to be able to add or remove features in as few operations as possible, touching as few files as possible.  Ideally you want to be able to add a feature without modifying any existing files.

Think about reusing just one of these web controls in another application, and it becomes pretty clear.